# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении (первый куплет известной песни): "Она читала мир(,) как роман, а он оказался повестью."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Она читала **мир как роман**, а он оказался повестью.

Нет обособления, значение **"в качестве".**

Оборот "как роман" является обстоятельством в основном сообщении, поэтому его нельзя обособить. Смысл таков: она **считала мир романом.**

Answer (score 1):

Запятая будет точно не ошибкой. Значение "в качестве" здесь притянуто за уши. "Она считала мир романом" – совершенно вольное толкование. Здесь обычный сравнительный оборот, особенно учитывая вторую основу.

Comment: Думаю,и отсутствие запятой также ошибкой не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу здесь ни сравнительного оборота, так как  отсутствует уподобление "подобно роману", ни приложения с "как" в значении "в качестве". Это обычное придаточное предложение, но неполное (полный вариант: "Она читала мир, как читают роман, а он оказался повестью".

Comment: Виктор, в чем разница межу "Ее голос звенел, как колокольчик" и "Она читала мир, как роман"? В первом случае сравнение, а во втором нет? На основании чего Вы это утверждаете?

Comment: Всё же думаю,что тут запятая не нужна,так как сравнительный оборот здесь тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым.